# Como verifico si un String es igual a "x" en c++?

Tags: c++, string

estoy aprendiendo c++ en la facultad y no se como hacer lo siguiente, tengo que acumular la $ facturada de una empresa con x sucursales pero por Zona, hice una estructura tengo todo bien, ahora el tema es no se como filtrar la facturacion por zona, escribi esto:

```
if(suc[i].zona == "Norte"){
                    totalzonan += suc[i].facturacion;
                    }
```

Eso es lo que se me ocurrio pero evidentemente no anda. Desde ya gracias.
Error:  ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer|

Estructura:

```
struct Sucursal{
int id;
char direccion[20];
char zona[20];
float facturacion;
}suc[25];
```

Comment: Hola. El código así como está, sin contexto, es difícil de juzgar. Si incluyes el cómo creaste la estructura, es más fácil decir si el código que muestras hace lo que esperas.

Comment: el operador `=`, en c++, es un operador de asignación, no de comparación. Si quieres comparar, utiliza `==`.

Comment: @Alfabravo ahi agregue la estructura.

Comment: @jachguate aunque ponga == me tira error, me dice iso c++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba con: `if (std::strcmp(suc[i].zona, "Norte") == 0)` quita el `std::` si tienes `using namespace std;` en el programa.

Si no funciona, es posible que tengas que convertir "Norte" en otro array de char:

```
char *norteChar = "Norte";

if (std::strcmp(suc[i].zona, norteChar) == 0) {
    totalzonan += suc[i].facturacion;
}
```

Estás comparando un array de char, eso no se puede hacer tan fácilmente en C++, porque estás jugando con punteros (de ahí el error que ves). No estás comparando strings, como dice el título de la pregunta.

Comment: ahora lo implemento y te cuento si funciona, gracias

Comment: bueno, ya no me tira error, pero cuando lo quiero imprimir me tira un numero cualquiera, como 6749892, y si alguna zona no le cargo facturacion tambien le pone un numero parecido

Comment: @MrBean has inicializado la variable `totalzonan`?, si no la inicializas es posible que tenga basura que suena a lo que te ocurre. En algún lugar inicializala a 0 `totalzonan = 0`. O quizá sea la variable `facturacion` de tu `struct`, no conozco el código, no puedo ayudarte más. Igualmente, si tienes algún otro problema, lo mejor es que abras otra pregunta (a menos que esté relacionado con el mismo problema, pero yo creo que es otro). Pon un enlace aquí si lo haces y quieres que le eche un ojo. Si la comparación funciona, cierra esta pregunta :-).

Comment: funciono, muchisimas gracias. Arregle el numero basura iniciandolo en 0 a cada zona. Fue raro encima porque probe con las 4 zonas, y por no se que razon una de las 4 me mostraba el numero correcto. Pero bueno inicie todo en 0 y anda perfecto, devuelta muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

**Opción C**

Dices que estás programando en C++ pero el código no tiene nada que sea propio de este lenguaje:

```
#include <string.h>

if( strcmp(suc[i].zona, "Norte") == 0 )
{
}
```

**Opción C++**

Usa `std::string`, que para eso está:

```
#include <string>

struct Sucursal{
  int id;
  std::string direccion;
  std::string zona;
  float facturacion;
} suc[25];

if( suc[i].zona == "Norte" )
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar la función compare de c++

```
#include <string>

struct Sucursal{
  int id;
  std::string direccion;
  std::string zona;
  float facturacion;
} suc[25];

if( suc[i].zona.compare("Norte") == 0 )
{
}
```